# Is there a way to reduce down the size of the pickle file for PyCaret models?

Tags: pickle, pycaret

I tried to compress a pickle file representing a PyCaret model.

```py
import joblib
joblib.dump('my_file.pkl',  'new_file.pkl.z',compress=3)
```

The above code didn't work.

How can I reduce the size of a pickle file for PyCaret models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call the joblib.dump function yourself, you should call the PyCaret save function directly on the loaded model as follows:

```
from pycaret.regression import load_model, save_model

your_model = load_model('my_file.pkl')
save_model(your_model, f'my_file.pkl', **{"compress":3})
```

*Example above is for a regression model*

For reference:
Pycaret calls the jolib.dump function [here](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/cda680e1c7e03926a42fd395b3ffb70c139fd378/pycaret/internal/persistence.py#L323) passing any given kwargs.